# Assign singleton array to element of array with Numba

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling, runtime-error, numba

I am trying to assign a singleton array to a specific element in a Numpy array using Numba's `nopython` mode but I get a `TypeError` and I can't figure out why. It works just fine without Numba. My MCVE is below.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit


@jit(nopython=True)
def mcve():
    tmp = np.zeros((2,2))
    tmp[0, 0] = np.array([0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mcve()
```

The error I get is the following.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Dropbox/Work/Stockholms universitet/Uppsatser/Hyresregleringen/supplementary/pythontest/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    mcve()
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 348, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 315, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot resolve setitem: array(float64, 2d, C)[(0, 0)] = array(int64, 1d, C)
```

I can get around the error by rewriting the function's second line to `tmp[0, 0] = np.array([0])[0]`. That is, by extracting the singleton's first element. But should this really be necessary? Or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Without Numba this works only on 1D-arrays with size one. The problem may be, that Numba can't check the size of arrays (only numdims, contigous, dtype) at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works just fine without Numba

Yes, but numba is about making trade-offs. You sacrifice some options and convenience for speed.

> I can't figure out why.

Because (currently) there's no conversion (or overload) that supports setting a single value of an array to a 1d array (even if it contains only one item).

> But should this really be necessary?

Probably not. But in general it's probably an error to **assign an array to one element** so I (personally) like that it raises an error at compile time instead of at run-time.

Note that the generalized cases already support different dimensional arrays:

For example:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def mcve():
    tmp = np.zeros((2,2))
    tmp[0:1, 0:1] = np.array([2])

@jit(nopython=True)
def mcve():
    tmp = np.zeros((2,2))
    tmp[0:1, 0:1] = 2

@jit(nopython=True)
def mcve():
    tmp = np.zeros((2,2))
    tmp[0:1, 0:1] = np.array([[[[5]]]])
```

But these are cases that can only be evaluated at run-time and are more generalized.